# Want to add the selectedValue also in the xaml along with the selected Text in my wpf window

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a compbobox with the following information

```
<ComboBox 
   Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="ComboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Height="21"> 
   <ComboBoxItem Content="All " ></ComboBoxItem> 
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Printed"></ComboBoxItem> 
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Unprinted"></ComboBoxItem> 
</ComboBox>
```

I want to also add the selected value for all being 2 printed being 1 and unprinted being 0 is there a way to add it in the xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer

Selected Value will then work because it will retrieve whatever is in Tag of the selected item.

Comment: you need to indent code 4 spaces if you want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you reversed the order of your ComboBoxItem declarations, then the property `SelectedIndex` on the `ComboBox` would yield these results.

Though its not a very scalable solution. You might want to try creating a collection of enumerated types and then binding that to the `ItemsSource` of the ComboBox and then investigating the `SelectedItem` to see which item has been selected.

Hope it helps.